# "Soft link" in dropbox folders

Tags: dropbox

I have one folder under `root/Apps` called `Marketring`.

I have another folder `root/Marketing-Tools/Products`.

I would like that when my users reaches `root/Apps/Marketing` it will actually be `root/Marketing-Tools/Products` - the same as I can do in linux, but I want to do it in dropbox.

The reason is, because I can create an app with folder access that is located under Apps folder and this way I can give access to `root/Marketing-Tools/Products`.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. The limitation is that Dropbox will sync the directory only per Dropbox session. This is to prevent symlink looping. You can read a deeper explanation in this Dropbox thread: [Dropbox not syncing properly with folders created by symbolic links](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Syncing-and-uploads/Dropbox-not-syncing-properly-with-folders-created-by-symbolic/td-p/28266)